# Infowindow false positioned

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I'm quite new to Google Maps API 3 and can't figure out the following error: All clicks on my markers open the infowindow on the same marker (bad), but with different text (good).
I'm pulling the data out of wordpress custom meta data into an xml, which i then parse; What makes me wondering is the fact that generating the markers works this way, but adding the listener for the infowindow obviously fails.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Live demo at:
http://goo.gl/9seK9

Code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var infowindow;
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(47.580231,13.771362);
    var settings = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: latlng,
        panControl: true,
        zoomControl: true,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        disableDefaultUI:true,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), settings);


    jQuery.get("http://rundumadum.eu/de/wp-content/themes/rud/rundumadumMap.xml", {}, function(data) {
        var xmllength = $(data).find("mymarkers").children().size();
        var supermarkers = [];

        jQuery(data).find("mymarker").each(function() {
                var myid = $(this).find("id").text();
                var mytitle = $(this).find("title").text();
                var mylink = $(this).find("link").text();
                var mylocation = $(this).find("location").text();

                var mysplits = mylocation.split(",");
                var mylat = mysplits[0];
                var mylng = mysplits[1];
                var mylatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(mylat), parseFloat(mylng));  
                var myinfo = "<a href="+mylink+">"+mytitle+"</a>";
                var marker = createMyMarker(mytitle, myinfo, mylink, mylatlng);
        });
    });


    function createMyMarker(mytitle, myinfo, mylink, mylatlng) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: mylatlng, 
            map: map,
            clickable:true,
            icon:'http://rundumadum.eu/de/wp-content/themes/rud/static/img/markerTest.png',
            html: '<a href="'+mylink+'">'+mytitle+'</a>'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
            infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: myinfo});
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    }
    return marker;

});
```

Would be grateful for any ideas ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I notice is that the `marker` you are creating in `createMyMarker` is not declared using `var marker`, so it looks like you are inadvertently creating a global `marker` reference. Also, it appears that the statement: `return marker` is actually after the end of your `createMyMarker` function, although that may just be a typo that was introduced when you set up your code sample in your question.

At any rate, I believe if you change the code in `createMyMarker` to declare the marker using `var marker` within that function, it will give you better results.

Comment: Thanks for your input.
I added the var-thing but nothing changed.
Which lead me to think about this line:

    if (infowindow) infowindow.close();

guess what, that was the problem ;-)
should have been like this:

    if (infowindow) {
    infowindow.close();
    }

thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Many times, just walking through your question to explain it to others will help you see something like this and then you figure out the problem. Glad I could help, even indirectly.